# Encoding special characters in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am making a new development, and I have to use an existing mySQL database. The management is made with phpMyAdmin.

The problem is that there are stored several data with special chars like `MarÃ­a`. Is it possible to fix it in the database?

The database and tables was originally encoded as `utf-8` and now it has been changed to `latin1_spanish_ci`.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "special character". There are only characters, lots of them. What should be "special" about some of them?

Comment: A conversion from UTF-8 encoding to an 8bit encoding is not reversable automatically, since information is missing if the data really has somehow been converted. Reason is that such conversion is a mapping of a huge to a small value set, so multiple values are mapped onto the same value. Such conversion immanently has to destroy information, it is impossible to tell from which of the many possible source value a target value has been mapped.

Comment: @arkascha special characters in my case are á, é, ñ, ç, etc. So there is no statement or option to convert automatically an Ã+ to its equivalent, an ñ , isn't it? Thank you

Comment: don' change in phpmyadmin. Just set the encoding attribute in your front-end file. It will automatically gets converted. Thanks.

Comment: If you really have `Ã+` in your strings, so two byte sequences, then chances are that the data has _not_ been converted as you claimed, but is merely interpreted now as 8bit encoded. If so, then simply changing the encoding notation back should fix the issue.

Comment: It doesn't work. The problem is that before changing the encoding, the characters were stored in the wrong format, so I really have in the database varchars which contain the characters Ã+ or whatever... It isn't just an interpretation of the information stored

Answer (score 1):

Which phpMyAdmin version are you using? Recent versions try to change the collation for you (it shows a warning, but generally this conversion is relatively safe. The usual warnings about backups apply, of course).

When you tried to change the collation on the Structure page, you should have seen a notice like this:

[image: Change collation confirmation]

If you don't see that on the Structure page, I suggest upgrading your phpMyAdmin. [This feature was introduced](https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/feature-requests/946/) in version 4.5.0, which was released in the fall of 2015.

Comment: I am using the version 3.5.2.2, and I can't change it because of "company policy", but thank you anyway

Comment: That's unfortunate. I feel for you :-)